# If it is true that you didn't study yesterday, you will fail the test tomorrow - wonder whether to use this construction

Tags: conditionals

**Question 1**

The situation is that: my friend said his neighbor was noisy yesterday, but he also said he wore headphones at the time. So, I ask him how he was able to hear his neighbor's voice while having headphones on.

Are (1) and (2) both ok to use? Do they mean the same?

My question to him:

(1)

> If it is true that you wore headphones yesterday, how were you able to hear your neighbor's voice?

(2)

> If you wore headphones yesterday, how were you able to hear your neighbor's voice?

---

**Question 2**

The situation is that: My friend is always hardworking, but he said he did not study yesterday, and the test is coming tomorrow. So I ask him a question about it.

Are (3) and (4) both ok to use? Do they mean the same?

My responses to him:

(3)

> If it is true that you didn't study yesterday, you will fail the test tomorrow. You are not the kind of student who fails a test.

(4)

> If you didn't study yesterday, you will fail the test tomorrow. You are not the kind of student who fails a test.

Comment: In both cases the sentences mean the same; adding 'If it is true' merely implies that you suspect the other person may not be telling the truth! Surely this is not unique to English?

Comment: @KateBunting, that is the answer! :D

Comment: Vincentlin: In both cases you have used the construction "I ask him". This is unusual. "I asked him" would be more comfortable and more typical in this case.

Comment: My guess is there are ***no*** contexts where including ***it is true that*** after ***if*** makes any real difference to the meaning. All it does is add a little "emphasis" - usually implying that the speaker thinks that the relevant assertion ***isn't*** true.